# Docusign Recipient view URL bypass the ID verification step

Tags: docusignapi

We have integrated docusign into our application and are able to create an Envelope using predefined template, and redirect to an embedded recipient view url generated by the docusign API.

After we added Docusign ID Verification to the recipient in the template, the embedded recipient view url generated via docusign API directly redirected to the document view page. It just totally skipped ID verification step. Checked the link in the email, it worked well and went to the start page of the ID verification process.

Is there any API can create the url same as the one in the mail?

Answer (score 0):

## Update

IDV now supports embedded signing. The only issue is that an iframe **cannot be used**.

Instead, either redirect your app to the embedded signing ceremony or open the signing ceremony in a new tab (and then later close the tab).

### Live example

You can try out embedded signing with IDV via the [API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=ID%20Verify)

You will need to input the IDV Workflow ID from the eSign admin app. You also need to enter your full legal name as it is shown in your government ID. You do not need a valid email address since embedded signing is used.